# Mockito anyInt not working

Tags: android, mockito

I'm new to Mockito and can not get the basic `anyInt()` method to work. What am I missing? Here's my test.

```
public class SpanPainterTest {
@Test
  public void simpleTest () {
    SpannableString mockSpanString = mock(SpannableString.class);

    SpanPainter painter = new SpanPainter();
    painter.applyColor(mockSpanString);

    verify(mockSpanString).charAt(anyInt());
    verify(mockSpanString).equals(anyInt());
  }
}
```

Here's the painter class.

```
public class SpanPainter {
  public SpannableString applyColor(SpannableString span) {
  span.charAt(7);
  span.equals(0);
  return span;
  }
}
```

When I comment out '`verify...charAt(anyInt()));`' line, then the test passes, so `anyInt()` works for the `equals()` method.

Comment: Do you know what the charAt function does? It returns a value at the given position. What are you trying to test?

Comment: I'm trying to test if the applyColor() method calls the charAt() method with any integer. My real test is actually more complicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973481/android-junit-tests-cant-call-any-android-api  However, at this point I would just like to know if anyInt may be the problem.

Comment: This `span.charAt(7);` does not modify the span object in any way so there is no way of testing this. You cannot know if a method has been called on an object unless it changes its state and you test the state change.

Comment: The `charAt` method is `final` and final methods cannot be mocked.

Comment: okay it seems as though verify doesn't work on methods that are final. I'll accept this answer if made into an 'Answer'. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `charAt` method is `final` and final methods cannot be mocked.

Have a look at [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) ([PowerMockito](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.6.2)) to mock final methods.